# How to find patch release date

Tags: history-of

I want to use a feature included in Patch 7.4.1154.

From [vim-history](https://github.com/vim/vim-history), I see releases:

- v8.0 - 12 September, 2016
- v7.4 - 10 August, 2013

There's a few years between them.

How do I find the release date of Patch 7.4.1154 itself?

Comment: For patches commited in git: https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1154  (cheers @filbranden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, Bram tags every numbered patch of vim with a tag of the form `v{patch_num}`.

If you have access to a local clone of the vim repository (https://github.com/vim/vim), the release date can be found using `git show`:

```
VER=7.4.1154
git show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%cd' v${VER}

Sat Jan 23 19:46:28 2016 +0100
```

The date can also be found without cloning through the github API:

```
BASE=https://api.github.com/repos/vim/vim/git
VER=7.4.1154
SHA=$(curl -s "${BASE}/refs/tags/v${VER}" | jq -r '.object.sha')
curl -s "${BASE}/commits/${SHA}" | jq -r '.committer.date'

2016-01-23T18:46:28Z
```

Note: these tags only go back so far (sometime after v7.0) since vim was not always tracked using git.  Also going back really far, the patch numbers are not always consistent, sometimes using four digits and sometimes 3 or fewer, rarely even using letters.

Comment: The Vim commit history for versions older than v7.0 is available at https://github.com/vim/vim-history

Answer (score 1):

Patch 7.4.1154, that introduces `jsonencode()` and `jsondecode()` (also constants `v:true`, `v:false`, `v:null` and `v:none`), was introduced in [commit 520e1e41f35b063](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/520e1e41f35b063ede63b41738c82d6636e78c34) from January 23rd, 2016.

Vim development assigns a patch number for each commit that goes into the code base, so it's usually easy to track a specific commit by looking at the history (on GitHub, for example.)

Vim also typically creates git "tags" for each version number. In this specific case, you can find the tag for this specific version under URL https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1154

It gets harder to track Vim versions under 7.4, patches were not always cleanly numbered and directly correlated to a specific commit then. Also, GitHub starts with Vim 7.0 (from June 13th, 2004), so tracking patches or features on earlier Vim 6 or Vim 5 is even harder.

Comment: Easy to do it in the browser, and without needing to remember anything (just navigate to the tags page).